# Problem on Maclaurin's expansion of $\sin 2x$.

Tags: calculus

Let $g(x)$ be the Maclaurin's expansion of $\sin 2x$. If $\sin 2x$ is approximated by $g(x)$ so that the error is atmost $\frac{1250}{3}  \times 10^{-4}$ for $0≤x≤1/2$, then what is the minimum number of non zero terms in $g(x) ?$

My attempt:

Error term is given by 
$R_{n} = \frac{x^n}{n!} f^{n} ( \theta x)= \frac{x^n}{n!}2^{n} sin(2 \theta x + n \pi /2)$

Then I tried to differentiate the function with respect to $x$ to get maximum error. But couldn't find any.

How to proceed$?$

Comment: The way you wrote down the error is confusing. You do not need to find the maximum of $R_n$ , you only have to bound $|R_n|$ from above.

Comment: Hint : The sine is always between $-1$ and $1$